# Problems with Linux OS in a Lenovo ideapad laptop

Tags: system-installation, kernel, touchpad, lenovo

I had a hard time installing ubuntu on my ideapad 330s-15ARR with Ryzen 3. Then, i have experience a lot of issue like not working wi-fi or not working touchpad. I already fix the wi-fi problem, but the main issue with my lapton is that i have constantly (Almost every time i used my laptop) system freezes with weird screen problems that force me to power-cycle my computer. I tried  a lot of tips but neither tabs nor terminal works... so only shut down cut the problem.

My current kernel is: 5.4.0-42-generic

If the is a way to fix this problem i will appreciate any help since i decided to reinstall my OS.Also, if any other linux distro works fine or has less problems, specially not freezes on the system, with this lenovo model i receive all of your recommendation.

Thanks you all in advanced.

Comment: Is your BIOS firmware up t o date also (version 7WCN38WW)?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research and refusing to recompile the graphics stack manually I found you need to do 2 things to almost completely resolve this issue:  set a cstate restriction parameter for the kernel in `/etc/default/grub` and update the AMD graphics driver.

Open Terminal and open the file for editing with root privileges, for example (if you don't have mousepad you could use nano)

```
sudo mousepad /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` so that after your edit it includes the parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`, for example mine says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

You can keep other parameters, such as `quiet` and `splash` which may be there already.

save and exit the text editor, and run this command to update the GRUB configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now add a PPA for AMD graphics drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Now reboot.

This solution should work for other flavors of Linux (ie mint, mx, manjaro etc...) and other AMD powered machines experiencing this issue.

Do not use screen lock or system suspend and you will most likely never have a freeze again!

When I choose to stop being lazy and resolve system lock freeze issues I will update this response.

AMD has not released any official proprietary drivers for Ubuntu 20.04 as of this posting, when and if they do, I would recommend trying them.